# How to use GStreamer interlace element?

Tags: gstreamer, video-capture

I have a source of progressive video that I want to convert to interlaced fields. From one progressive frame, I want to generate two interlaced fields, each containing either the odd or the even lines.

In GStreamer terminology, each input buffer contains one progressive frame that I want to convert into two buffers, each containing one field.

I was expecting the first pipeline below to produce 20 files of size 640 * 240 * 2 and the second one to produce 10 files of size 640 * 480 * 2.

But they both produce 10 files of size 640 * 480 * 2, so the interlace element seems to do nothing.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=ball num-buffers=10 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! interlace ! multifilesink location=c:\x_%d.raw

gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc pattern=ball num-buffers=10 ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,width=640,height=480 ! multifilesink location=c:\x_%d.raw
```

Comment: No, you will get one frame with both fields.

Comment: Is there an element I could use to produce two buffers from one, shallow-copying? I'm thinking to add meta on each for an offset and stride and half the height.